# Task returns IsCompleted == true before it is actually completed

Tags: c#, asp.net, async-await, task-parallel-library

I have two Task groups I want to run one after another in ASP.NET application.

```
isLogin = false;

Task[] firstBatch = 
{
    new Task(async () => isLogin = await webserviceclient.Login())
};
firstBatch.ForEach(t => t.Start());
Task.WaitAll(firstBatch);



Task[] secondBatch = 
{
    new Task(async () => UsersList1 = isLogin ? await webserviceclient.GetAllUsers(1) : null),
    new Task(async () => UsersList2 = isLogin ? await webserviceclient.GetAllUsers(2) : null)
};
secondBatch.ForEach(t => t.Start());
Task.WaitAll(secondBatch);
```

In `webserviceclient.Login()` I have `await _client.GetAsync(_baseUri).ConfigureAwait(false)` called. As for the `webserviceclient.GetAllUsers()` it does not matter what i do because it never run. I figured that after `await _client.GetAsync(_baseUri)` is called `firstBatch[0].IsCompleted` for unknown reason is set to true and `secondBatch` begins to execute. `await _client.GetAsync(_baseUri)` stops awaiting actually after `Task.WaitAll(secondBatch);` command. Which is obviously not what I want here.

It looks like some kind of deadlock but I do not see where is the problem.

Comment: Creating lots of `Task`s manually, `Start`ing them separately and mixing in `async`/`await`. Usually a recipe for problems. I strongly suspect if you inspect all of the actual types at runtime you'll find that some items you thought were plain `Task`s are in fact `Task<Task>` - and so when the outer Task is complete it says nothing about whether the inner Task is.

Comment: you can try remove `ConfigureAwait ` from your call API , as the the docuemntation say that the task is wrapped inside another task.

Comment: Don't use `new Task` at all, ever, unless you are completely aware of what you are doing, this is your problem combined with the fact you are passing an async lambda to an Action which is going to run unobserved, instead use `Task.Run`

Comment: Tasks aren't threads. There's never any good reason for cold tasks that get started with a call to `.Start()`. `webserviceclient.Login()` already returns a task. If you wanted to log into multiple services you could put *these* tasks into a list and use `var loginResults=Task.WhenAll(tasks)` to await all of them *and* inspect their results. Your current code doesn't even do that, because the value of `isLogin` is arbitrary - it will be the value returned by the last task to complete. Not even the last task in the array

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would re-write your code as follows:

```cs
var isLogin = false;
isLogin = await webserviceclient.Login();

if(isLogin)
{
    var secondBatch = new []
    {
        webserviceclient.GetAllUsers(1),
        webserviceclient.GetAllUsers(2)
    }; 
    var userResults = await Task.WhenAll(secondBatch);
}
```

Comment: I can see two problems. The second is that the [`Task.WhenAll(Task[])`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task.whenall#System_Threading_Tasks_Task_WhenAll_System_Threading_Tasks_Task___) method returns a `Task`, not a `Task<Result>`, so it can't convey a value for the `userResults` variable.

Comment: @TheodorZoulias what's the first problem? as to the second, I think you're looking at the wrong overload on that page? `Task.WhenAll(IEnumerable<Task<TResult>>)` returns a `Task<TResult[]>`. In the above example, `userResults[0]` will have the result of `await webserviceclient.GetAllUsers(1)`

Comment: Agreed, this wouldn't compile with the awaits, once you await GetAllUsers(x), its not a task anymore and cant be assigned to an array of task

Answer (score 0):

Answers in the comments solved the issue. Thanks.

```
isLogin = false;

Task[] firstBatch = 
{
    Task.Run(async () => isLogin = await webserviceclient.Login())
};
Task.WaitAll(firstBatch);



Task[] secondBatch = 
{
    Task.Run(async () => UsersList1 = isLogin ? await webserviceclient.GetAllUsers(1) : null),
    Task.Run(async () => UsersList2 = isLogin ? await webserviceclient.GetAllUsers(2) : null)
};
Task.WaitAll(secondBatch);
```

As for comment about `var loginResults=Task.WhenAll(tasks)` I agree but I never intended to run more than one `webserviceclient.Login()` there anyway. As it is only an example, tasks in the first group are different and results are unrelated to other tasks inside the same group.

Comment: The "first batch" code is equivalent to this: `bool isLogin = Task.Run(() => webserviceclient.Login()).Result;`. This is not good code. You are blocking two `ThreadPool` threads in order to do work that probably [doesn't require any thread](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/11/there-is-no-thread.html) at all. You have a scalability killer right there.